# input text, input password, radiobutton, checkbox, textarea etc in java

Tags: java, html

Where can I find information like how to make input text, input password, radiobutton, checkbox and textarea in a software made with java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is a good set of Sun tutorials.](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html)

Comment: Please note the [html] tag, I don't think Swing is appropriate here.

Comment: good point, if this is for HTML, i will delete the answer, if it is for 'software made with java' this would be fitting.

Comment: I used the html tag, because I took the names input text, input password, radiobutton, checkbox and textarea from html and I didn't know how to talk about them with java terms.

Comment: The original question did not mention HTML or Swing. Yes it's in the tag but should have been mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the GUI toolkit you are using.

You've tagged this HTML, so if you are generating webpages — just output the HTML for the form controls you want.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what framework you choose to use for your web application. The [Java EE Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/) is a good place to start and it covers Servlets, JSP and Java Server Faces. Other web-enabling frameworks include:

- [Apache Struts](http://struts.apache.org/)
- [Spring MVC](http://www.springsource.org/)
- [Stripes](http://www.stripesframework.org)
- [Wicket](http://wicket.apache.org/)
- [Tapestry](http://tapestry.apache.org/)